# Clearing of app cache in iOS works for Google+ login, but doesn't work for Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

In my app I implemented login using Facebook and Google+. 
Given scenario:

- I logged in using fb account 1
- I would like to login using fb account 2, so I log out
- On safari view I get message "You have already granted permissions to your app"

Which is ok end expected. User needs to log out from Safari browser.
But I would like to do it by myself by cleaning cookies and URLCache:

```
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
    URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0

    if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
        for cookie in cookies {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
```

This code erases data for Google+, but doesn't change anything for Facebook. Is it the expected behavior? Why?
If no - what is the way to clean Facebook data as well?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way. When you use FB to login you can first use logout

```
FBSDKLoginManager *manager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
//manager.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
[manager logOut];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I use FBSDKLoginManager().logOut() during logout. After this I clear cache.  So I already use this :)